# Vuex watch all object subproperties

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am watching a Vuex object's individual properties like so:

```js
this.$store.watch( function(state) {return state.views.height}, function() { //do something } )
this.$store.watch( function(state) {return state.views.width}, function() { //do something } )
```

Is it possible to watch all of the object properties of `state.views` without specifying the individual properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vuex's `watch` method takes the same `options` argument from Vue's [`$watch`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch) method. There's a `deep` option that allows you to watch all changes to subproperties.

```js
store.watch(
  state => state.views,
  views => console.log('change', views.height, views.width),
  { deep: true } // <-- options
)
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-pine-xf2yt?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fstore.js&theme=dark)